# Getting Rid of Software Records for Software installed on an external disk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, uninstall, libreoffice

So I'm cleaning out an old computer, and several of the programs it thinks it has were actually installed on an old drive, that's now gone. For some of them, it prompts to get rid of them because it can't find the drive, so that's all well and good.

But, for LibreOffice and a couple of others, it tries to run the LibreOffice Uninstaller, and only quits with a fatal error when the LibreOffice uninstaller can't find the drive.

The difference here is that in the first case, Windows can't even find the drive with the uninstallers on them, so it prompts to remove them; but in the second, its found the uninstallers on the local disk somewhere and is trying to run them, prompting a fatal error when the uninstaller can't find them.

What should I do here? How can I remove what's left of these programs/erase their names from the family tree?

Thanks!

evamvid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I remove leftovers after uninstalling programs?

There are several programs that will clean up after an uninstall that did not complete successfully.

---

#### Iobit Unstaller

> IObit Uninstaller 3 is a light and FREE uninstall tool that helps you
> to remove unwanted programs and leftovers completely without any
> hassle. It detects and categorizes all of the installed programs, and
> allows bulk uninstallation with just ONE click!

Source [IObit Uninstaller 3](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)

---

#### Revo Uninstaller

> Revo Uninstaller Pro helps you to uninstall software and remove unwanted programs installed on your computer easily! Even if you have problems uninstalling and cannot uninstall them from "Windows Programs and Features (Add or Remove Programs)" control panel applet.
>
> Revo Uninstaller is a much faster and more powerful alternative to "Windows Programs and Features (Add or Remove Programs)" applet! It has very powerful features to uninstall and remove programs.

There is a freeware version available.

Source [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [IObit Uninstaller 3](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html) or [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Answer (score 2):

There is software you can use to remove entries from the softwarelist or do it manually by editing the registry, but by using this, you risk that shared files remain in your windows system folder that can be removed.

If you want to be absolutely sure, install LibreOffice again onto the pc, then uninstall it. The same process can be used for all programs missing. If a program cannot be installed nor uninstalled, you can remove it manually by going to the following registry key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Here, all subfolders are installed programs. The DisplayName will tell you the name of the program. It is advised to export the entire Uninstall branch so you can undo the changes if necessary.

**Editing the registry is at your own risk and should be avoided if you have no idea what you're doing.**

Comment: For software installed using 32-bit installer (such as Inno Setup) on 64-it system, you need to check 32-bit key in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (note the `WOW6432Node`).