# Can't install runway on windows after a failed installation

Tags: windows-10, installation

The default location of runway is in the `%AppData%` location.
I didn't like this location so I choose `C:/Program Files` instead.

Bad idea, the installation failed, and now when I try to install it somewhere else I get:

[image]

It hangs here:
[image]

I also tried to install for all users instead, I tried tons of different locations, I tried running setup as an administrator. But no matter what, it get's stuck on it's install...

Is there anyway of fixing this?

Comment: Does my answer in https://superuser.com/questions/938946/getting-rid-of-software-records-for-software-installed-on-an-external-disk work for you?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I tried https://www.iobit.com/en/advanceduninstaller.php as listed in that post. After the uninstal it still said there was a per -user installation, but this time it was able to finish the installation!