# I cannot uninstall python after deleting program cache

Tags: python, uninstall, cache

I am really really new to python so please do not assume I understand  any lingo or what I am doing in any way.

I am using a windows machine with windows-10 professional.

I recently tried to free up space on C by deleting cached things.. I obviously made a huge mistake when i deleted package cache.

While trying to install a new program to use (stable cascade)  I was getting the error 'NameError: name 'previewer''  which I was told is 'a bad python install error' and  that the solution would be to uninstall all my versions of python and start again..

Well all but one version uninstalled successfully,

The one that remains gives me this error in the picture below:

[image: error msg]

I cannot install python fresh because it says I already have a newer version of it, (I don't, nothing works) but i cant uninstall or modify it either because it cant find that package cache.

I tried uninstalling and deleting things with revo uninstaller - did not fix it.

I really messed up. Please help

Comment: Have you restarted?

Comment: Have you tried Iobit Unistaller? [windows 7 - Getting Rid of Software Records for Software installed on an external disk? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/938946/getting-rid-of-software-records-for-software-installed-on-an-external-disk/938968#938968)

Comment: The error is indicating that while Windows thinks Python is installed it actually isn’t

Comment: restarted - yes - did not fix it

- trying L0bit now-

-ramhound - seriously? ...

Comment: l0bit cant find it to uninstall it